# Bison: How to detect duplicated keywords in sql?

Tags: sql, parsing, bison

I am reading this book for sql parsing - https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/flex-bison/9780596805418/ch04.html. Here below detecting the duplicates of ALL, DISTINCT, what I do not understand was how the bitwise AND can detect the duplicates ALL, DISTINCT etc.  Why bitwise comparison with 01, 02 and 04 for ALL, DISTINCT, and DISTINCTROW in below ?

```
select_opts:                          { $$ = 0; }
| select_opts ALL                 
   { if($1 & 01) yyerror("duplicate ALL option"); $$ = $1 | 01; }
| select_opts DISTINCT            
   { if($1 & 02) yyerror("duplicate DISTINCT option"); $$ = $1 | 02; }
| select_opts DISTINCTROW         
   { if($1 & 04) yyerror("duplicate DISTINCTROW option"); $$ = $1 | 04; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in `if (condition) statement1; statement2;`, `statement2;` is not conditional on `condition`.

At the end of the lines, you see `$$ = $1 | 01;` (or `02`/`04`). This gets executed if an `ALL` keyword (or `DISTINCT`/`DISTINCTROW`) is seen regardless of whether it was already seen before.

Since this keeps track of the `ALL` keyword in the bit with value 1 once it's first seen, on a later appearance of that keyword, extracting the bit with value 1 can tell you whether it was already seen before.

Comment: so those 01 / 02 / 04 values were just ASSIGNED to ALL, DISTINCT and DISTINCTROW keywords in the bit ?  What does the usage/effect of "$$ = $1 | 01" etc. ?

Comment: @user3658306 I'm not sure I understand your question. There's nothing advanced going on, but there are several basic knowledge aspects that are easy to overlook if you're not familiar with them. Can you be more specific in your question, by explaining which parts you do understand?

Comment: I am wondering if there is any reason to have ALL (keyword) in the bit with the value 1 and have DISTINCT in the bit with the value 2 and etc.

Comment: @user3658306 It could have been the other way around just as well. The only important part is that separate bits are used, otherwise you get misleading diagnostics when combining `ALL` and `DISTINCT`: an error "duplicate DISTINCT option" when the `DISTINCT` keyword is only used once is not helpful to the user.

Comment: thanks a lot.  Looks like you are an expert on this.  I had a question sent to stackoverflow, not only was not answered, but also was removed.  Maybe you can help me with that ?

Comment: @user3658306 If you feel your question was removed in error, and the normal process (read up on why your question isn't appropriate in its current form, edit it to make it appropriate, wait for the community to respond) isn't working as it should, you can ask a question about it on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). If you do that and link to your question there, I'll be happy to take a look, although others will probably manage to answer sooner. It'll be hard to help other than that without more details, and those details, if needed, probably belong on Meta anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed the title name and content to post a question "bison/flex on sql parsing :  user entered column name was a keyword" on the regular stackoverflow , not the Meta one.